# newcommand: boldface is extended to next character

Tags: macros

I am using a newcommand like this

```
\newcommand{\gen}{\textbf{P1}\xspace}
```

and it works just fine. However in the text the boldface is always extended to the next character. For example

```
lorem ipsum \gen, foo bar
```

will result in

> lorem impsum **P1,** foo bar

and not

> lorem impsum **P1**, foo bar

as intended.

Any help with this highly appreciated.

Cheers

Philipp

Comment: Erh, not understood at all, that macro does not bleed boldface. Please provide a full minimal example so we can compile the example as you are seeing it.

Comment: Plus those two *result* lines are the same.

Comment: Please post a _complete_ small document that shows this effect.

Comment: @daleif The comma is bold on the first one.

Comment: @percusse I see no boldface comma. If I try `\gen,` with `\showoutput`, I see `\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ,` which looks like medium series.

Comment: The described output is what you would get from `\newcommand{\gen}[1]{\textbf{P1#1}\xspace}`

Comment: @egreg I mean in the question.

Comment: I'm with @DavidCarlisle on this one. It seems that the OP is using a different definition than the one listed in the text. This is exactly why we want a proper MWE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

As can be seen in the above image, `\gen` does not make the following character bold.

The modified version `\genb` does make it bold, and pulls it before any added space (as can be seen with the **c**).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\gen}{\textbf{P1}\xspace}
\newcommand{\genb}[1]{\textbf{P1#1}\xspace}

\begin{document}

aaa \gen, bbb \gen ccc

aaa \genb, bbb \genb ccc

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! For some reason it appears to be solved now, but I am using a different computer. Need to re-check on my machine at home.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2334921 please (for next time) always make a complete test document to include in the question, as in this answer. If you can't make a test document that reproduces the problem, you don't have a problem:-)